# Harmonic oscillator differential equation dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, harmonic-functions

Is $x''(t) = -ax$ (a simple harmonic oscillator) considered a one-dimensional dynamical system or two-dimensional?

If it is one dimensional, why is this possible? With a dynamical system, isnt it impossible for a one dimensional system to oscillate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a second order scalar equation. Its phase or state space has dimension two. The cited claim on non-oscillation is only true for scalar first-order autonomous equations.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to clarify, the phase/state space has dimension two because when you solve the equation it would yield two constants - is that right?

Comment: Or because if you transform it into an equivalent first order systems, this will be two-dimensional. But overall, this is the same statement.

Comment: I see. So x' = y, and y' = -ax. Thank you so much.